# Managing and Building Erlang Apps

Tags: erlang, gradle, buildr

Is it possible to use [Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) or [Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) to manage Erlang project deps and build/package the app itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess [rebar](http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html) is the closest thing to what you describe. It can be used to build and package Erlang applications, define pre-compile and post-compile operations and so on.